# Kafka Streams instances going in to DEAD state

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

We are using Kafka 0.10.2.0, kafka streams 1.1.0.
We have Kafka Cluster of 16 machines, and topic that is being consumed by Kafka Streams has 256 partitions. We spawned 400 instances of Kakfa Streams application.
We see that all of the StreamThreads go in to DEAD state.

```
[2018-05-25 05:59:29,282] INFO stream-thread [ksapp-19f923d7-5f9e-4137-b79f-ee20945a7dd7-StreamThread-1] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread)
[2018-05-25 05:59:29,282] INFO stream-client [ksapp-19f923d7-5f9e-4137-b79f-ee20945a7dd7] State transition from REBALANCING to ERROR (org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams)
[2018-05-25 05:59:29,282] WARN stream-client [ksapp-19f923d7-5f9e-4137-b79f-ee20945a7dd7] All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed. (org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams)
[2018-05-25 05:59:29,282] INFO stream-thread [ksapp-19f923d7-5f9e-4137-b79f-ee20945a7dd7-StreamThread-1] Shutdown complete (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread)
```

Please note that when we have only 100 kafka instances, things are working as expected. We see that instances are consuming messages from topic.

Comment: There should be an ERROR log with a full stack trace in case an exception happened that killed the thread. Can you share it?

Comment: [link](http://www.filedropper.com/ks)